# PDO && mysql insert query

Tags: php, pdo

I am building a commenting system. It works in the same way with MySQL, MySQLi and PDO.  I have a lot of customers therefore I will have multiple Ids.

In my insert query I am defining a FOREIGN KEY which is the `user_id` from the customer's table into the `notes` table.

My question is, after the `VALUES` attribute, what should be the first value to identify the specific id for the particular customer I am working on.

If I leave the value as `VALUES (1,...)` in my database, each comment will always be pointed at `user_id (1)`, what can I work on `user_id` `2` and `3`?

```
<?php
            // DEFINE QUERY HERE
            $query = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO `notes`(`user_id`,`entry`, registration_date)
                                    VALUES (1,:entry, NOW())");

            //EXCECUTE QUERY
            $query->bindValue(':entry', $_POST['entry']);
            $query->execute();
            echo '<span style="color:red;">Note Added </span>';
            $dbc = null;
        } else {
            echo '<span style="color:red;">Note was not added, insert Admin notes</span>';
        }
    }
    catch(PDOExeption $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need to insert a user id value, perhaps **:user** instead of the **1**

Comment: does :entry in VALUES need " ' "?

Comment: You should look at using an `auto_increment` column for `user_id`, which will increase automatically every time you insert a new row: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, remove the value 1 from your statement. Instead this, send the current post id and populate this variable dynamically. Also set the Id from your user table to auto incrementing.

Comment: yeah well haha no idea how to do that.. when the ID is coming from the auto increment from the database.. but that anyways sounds like an option

Comment: You can use a hidden input and populate it with the user_id. So you can send it to your statement.

Comment: Alternatively you can pick the `user_id` from the user session data